# WPF cannot set owner property after dialog is shown

Tags: c#, wpf

When i  change the owner of all windows displayed in my wpf application, some times i am getting exception "cannot set owner property after dialog is shown"

Code

```
foreach (Window vAlarmWindow in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (vAlarmWindow is AlarmWindow && this != vAlarmWindow.Owner && !vAlarmWindow.IsLoaded)
    {
        vAlarmWindow.Owner = this;
    }
}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: The window you are trying to set as owner is not visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the reason is that you have some `AlarmWindow` in that list which has already been shown and closed. When `Window` is closed it is unloaded.
Unfortunately for you there is no property in `Window` class that would tell you if it has been shown and closed. For that you would have to handle `Window.Closed` event and set some property in your `AlarmWindow` class